# Code highlighting of underscore.js templates in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, underscore.js

I use to keep my underscore.js templates in .html files but Netbeans gives syntax errors.

Is there a plugin for integrating underscore.js templates with Netbeans? If no, is there a method for setting up Netbeans to recognize the templates?

Answer (score 3):

There is no NetBeans plugin that supports underscore.js templating syntax.
There is a way to make NetBeans recognize any custom language, and it is long and difficult. Outlined here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/SyntaxColoringANTLR

The solution I found, thanks to Thomas Davis from http://backbonetutorials.com/, is using Sublime text editor, which does recognize underscore.js templating syntax, more or less well.